Azure Active Directory multi scheme authentication ASP.NET Core 3.1
I am using net core and I have my login system with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and I need to add Azure Active Directory, but I can't connect it correctly.
I have this code in my ConfigureServices():
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(40);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
});
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddAzureAD(options =>
{
    var azureADSettingService = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IAzureADSettingService>();

    var azure = azureADSettingService.GetBySubDomain(Subdomain);

    options.ClientId = azure.ClientId;
    options.ClientSecret = azure.ClientSecret;
    options.TenantId = azure.TenantId;
    options.Instance = azure.Instance;
    options.Domain = azure.Domain;
    options.CallbackPath = azure.CallbackPath;
});

services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
    options.HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.None;
    options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.ConsentCookie.IsEssential = true;
});

And in my Configure() method:
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

In my AccountController:
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Uri returnUrl = null)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action("SigningMicrosoft", "Account", values: null, protocol:       Request.Scheme);
    return Challenge(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl }, AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

Currently the screen keeps loading in the Microsoft login and does not authorize to enter the site.

We have official document here to demonstrate how to sign in with external account along with the default identity we already have. This will make you to sign in with microsoft account, and then your application will create a corresponding account into your database which is  mapping the microsoft account.


I have my login system with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and I need
to add Azure Active Directory

Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity means you are now using the default asp.net core identity, and microsoft has built-in feature to integrate Azure AD authentication into the default identity. We have tutorial here. It showed us how to integrate external auth provider like google/facebook.. including Azure AD. And we should know that after adding external authentication provider, there will be at least 2 kinds of account in the same app, maybe one user will have 2 accounts both belong to him, so that we make sure the 2 accounts have mapping relation ship so that the app should know user1@console.com and user1@xx.onmicrosoft.com are representing the same user. And this is already realized by the library.
Here's a summary for integrating AAD into the app. Firstly of all, I created a new asp.net core 3.1 mvc project, and choose Individual Account as authentication type in VS 2022, I can have a sign in page like below. Just like you see, it already prepared the scheme for allowing external authentication provider.

Then we require to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount which version should match .net core 3.1, and adding codes below in Startup.cs -> ConfigureService method.
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = "aad_client_id";
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = "client_secret";
});

Then we will be able to sign in with microsoft account, we will see a button like screenshot below.

